# "type mismatch" trying to hide rows using vba

Tags: vba, excel

What I want to do is hide rows so my interface is lighter but I get the following error message when I i compile my code:

> Type mismatch (Error 13)

```
Public Function keepAdditionalRowsHidden()

Dim startRow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

Dim startRowString As String
Dim endRowString As String

startRow = 40
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

startRowString = CStr(startRow)
endRowString = CStr(lastrow)

ActiveSheet.Rows("startRow:endRow").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one issue right off the bat.  When you are doing your `ActiveSheet.Rows("startRow:endRow").EntireRow.Hidden = True` you are not calling those variables, you are stating them as strings.

Try this instead:

`ActiveSheet.Rows(startrow & ":" & endrow).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

This way, you are properly calling the variables, and the only "string" is the : (colon).

Also, next time you ask please make sure you explain if you are receiving an error, or just not achieving the results you desire.  I am guessing you are getting a *type mismatch* error with this, but I cannot be sure.  This helps everyone better assist you.

Comment: Hi, this solved my challenge, but then there appeared a new one. Do you have any ideas how to hide rows from 50 at the end of the document. In my excel user creates and deletes rows which make hidden rows visible. The reason for question is that excel start to complain memory amount.

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my challenge, but is there cleaner way to define last row of the excel, like this way?

> endRow = 1048576

```
Public Function keepAdditionalRowsHidden()

        Dim startRow As Long
        Dim endRow As Long

        startRow = ER.row + 1

        endRow = 1048576 ' last row of the excel

        ActiveSheet.Rows(startRow & ":" & endRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Functioncode here
```